# Bought new iPhone 6s. Asking for different apple id. Why?

Tags: apple-id, iphone

My girlfriend's brother just ordered a new iPhone 6s and he tried setting up his phone but the store I believe keeps asking for a password for a Japanese registered email address. Assuming that's not meant to happen. Any reason this is happening? Is the phone refurbished or stolen and not new? Thanks for any info

Comment: Where is he buying the iPhone?

Comment: @fbara mobiles.co.uk it said the phone was new when he ordered

Comment: I would agree with @TMHahn's answer in that he either bought a refurb without realizing it or was misled in the purchase.

Comment: Is he able to use the phone at all?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like he has encountered [Activation Lock](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365). He can check that theory here:

https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

The information provided would seem to indicate the device has been used before.